# Javascript identify sum of array elements randomly located within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So.. `currentArray=[n1, n2, n3, n4, sum(currentArray), n5, n6]` <--psuedocode obv

So another way would be  `currentArray.push(sum(oldArray)).shuffle(random)` <--psuedo

I thought this would be as easy as using `Math.max(...array)`, like in this example..

`shuffled=[1, 12, 3, 6, 2]`

I would be looking for the 12 here, as removing the 12 would result in sum(array)=12.

However, it got confusing and difficult when the input had positive and negative numbers included.  As in this example..

`shuffled=[1, -3, -5, 7, 2]`

In this case, the solution would be 1, as removing the 1 would result in sum(array)=1

**UPDATE**

Question had a pretty simple, but not obvious solution, at least to me haha.  Here is the updated, working code.

```
Array.prototype.polysplice = function (criteria)  {
    this.splice(this.indexOf(criteria),1)
    return this }
    
Array.prototype.polysort = function () {
    return this.sort((a, b) => a - b)  }
    
Array.prototype.polysum = function (subject) {
    return this.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) }

const solution = shuffled => shuffled.polysplice(shuffled.polysum()/2).polysort()
```

**ORIGINAL**

My code, but obv its no bueno..

```
Array.prototype.sliceAll = function (criteria) {
    return this.filter(e=>e !== criteria) }
    
Array.prototype.polysort = function () {
    return this.sort((a, b) => a - b)  }
    
const solution = shuffled => shuffled.sliceAll(Math.max(...shuffled)).polysort()
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a unique solution.

Comment: @Barmar that is what I was afraid of.  idk how to even code that in an algorithm, unless the only way is to map each element, removing it and summing it's siblings to check if its the one.  agh!

Comment: Considering the simple answer, now I feel stupid for posting.  LOL

Comment: Simple things are hard to get. It's not stupidity. @BrianPatterson

Comment: Don't feel stupid, I didn't think of that answer, either. It's easy to miss things like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For both examples you can simply add all vars togehther and divide the sum by 2

> sum(array)/2

Comment: That's even simpler than the solution I was going to post, which is to sum the array, then subtract each element of the array and check whether that result is equal to the element.

Comment: Wow!  Duh right?   LOL!  Thanks much!   I knew someone on here would know a smart way to do it.  haha.

Comment: Beautiful answer :) @Johannes

Comment: Deceptively simple. Good intuition.